# Selective deletion by value in numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-slicing

EDITED: Refined problem statement

I am still figuring out the fancy options which are offered by the numpy library. Following topic came on my desk:

**Purpose:**
In a multi-dimensional array I select one column. This slicing works fine. But after that, values stored in another list need to be filtered out of the column values.

**Current status:**

```
array1 = np.asarray([[0,1,2],[1,0,3],[2,3,0]])
print(array1)
array1woZero = np.nonzero(array1)
print(array1woZero)
toBeRemoved = []
toBeRemoved.append(1)
print(toBeRemoved)   
column = array1[:,1]
result = np.delete(column,toBeRemoved)
```

The above mentioned code does not bring the expected result. In fact, the np.delete() command just removes the value at index 1 - but I would need the **value of 1** to be filtered out instead. What I also do not understand is the shape change when applying the nonzero to array1: While array1 is (3,3), the array1woZero turns out into a tuple of 2 dims with 6 values each.

```
0
Array of int64
(6,)
0
0
1
1
2
2

1
Array of int64
(6,)
1
2
0
2
0
1
```

My feeling is that I would require something like slicing with an exclusion operator. Do you have any hints for me to solve that? Is it necessary to use different data structures?

Comment: Look for boolean or logical indexing. You can use this to remove values from other arrays of the same shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the hint with the boolean masking very good and helped me to develop my own solution. The symbolic names in the following code snippets are different, but the idea should become clear anyway.

At the beginning, I have my overall searchSpace.

```
searchSpace = relativeDistances[currentNode,:]
```

Assume that its shape is (5,). My filter is defined on the indexes, i.e. range 0..4. Then I define another numpy array "filter" of same shape with all 1, and the values to be filtered out I set to 0.

```
filter = np.full(shape=nodeCount,fill_value=1,dtype=np.int32())
filter[0] = 0
filter[3] = 0
searchSpace = searchSpace * filter
minValue = searchSpace[searchSpace > 0].min()
neighborNode = np.where(searchSpace==minValue)
```

The filter array provides me the flexibility to adjust the filter later on as part of a loop. Using the element-wise multiplication with 0 and subsequent boolean masking, I can create my reduced searchSpace for minimum search. Compared to a separate array or list, I still have the original shape, which is required to get the correct index in the where-statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [18]: arr = np.asarray([[0,1,2],[1,0,3],[2,3,0]])                                     
In [19]: arr                                                                             
Out[19]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 0, 3],
       [2, 3, 0]])
```

`nonzero` gives the indices of all non-zero elements of its argument (`arr`):

```
In [20]: idx = np.nonzero(arr)                                                           
In [21]: idx                                                                             
Out[21]: (array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]), array([1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1]))
```

This is a tuple of arrays, one per dimension.  That output can be confusing, but it is easily used to return all of those non-zero elements:

```
In [22]: arr[idx]                                                                        
Out[22]: array([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3])
```

Indexing like this, with a pair of arrays, produces a 1d array.  In your example there is just one 0 per row, but in general that's not the case.

This is the same indexing - with 2 lists of the same length:

```
In [24]: arr[[0,0,1,1,2,2], [1,2,0,2,0,1]]                                               
Out[24]: array([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3])
```

`idx[0]` just selects on array of that tuple, the row indices.  That probably isn't what you want.  And I doubt if you want to apply `np.delete` to that tuple.

It's hard to tell from the description, and code, what you want.  Maybe that's because you don't understand what `nonzero` is producing.

We can also select the nonzero elements with boolean masking:

```
In [25]: arr>0                                                                           
Out[25]: 
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False]])
In [26]: arr[ arr>0 ]                                                                    
Out[26]: array([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Then we leave out the use of standard non-zero function. What do I want? 
Step 1: Select one column out of multi-dimensional array
Step 2: Filter out a collection of values (e.g. the "1", "33" and "5"). This collection is of variable/growing size, therefore I use list structure in the sample code.
Maybe in the end I could also use a for-loop over the whole column, but I am afraid of runtime increase due to too many iterations. Rather would like to use slicing power of numpy.

Comment: `arr[:, i]` is the `ith` column of the `arr` array.

Comment: The boolean masking example looks promising ... how would that look for multiple value list instead of the 0 in your example?